# I would like to pipe output of find to strip of the file and get only the directory name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Can you please help me what command do I need to use

Let say am trying to find out .git folder in a directory and want to strip out the .git and just get a directory name

Am trying this

```
find /home/madhu/release/workspace -type d -name '.git'
```

Output is

```
/home/madhu/release/workspace/admin/admin_test/.git
```

I just need to get the output as

```
home/madhu/release/workspace/admin/admin_test
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: just use `dirname` on the output..: `echo "$(driname "$out")"`

Comment: How can I pass the path of a file as an argument from command line ?

Comment: that seems like a different question, why don't you open a new thread with a little more detail about what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-exec` option of `find` together with the [`dirname`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) command:

```
find /path/to/files -type d -name '.git' -exec dirname {} +
```

Comment: Find home/madhu/release/workspace -type d dirname -name '.git' didn't work out am I using the correct one @hek2mgl

Comment: Find home/madhu/release/workspace -type d -name '.git' -exec dirname {} + didn't worked it tells me extra operand /path/to .git

Comment: Looks like you messed up the command line. Simply use the command I've posted and replace `/path/to/files` with `/home/madhu/release/workspace`

Comment: Am new to Linux Can you please tell me what does { } + do

Comment: It passes the filename to the command executed by `-exec`. Check `man find`

Comment: I have a question here I would like to pass the path of a file as an argument how can I do this ?